# Working with UUID in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm looking to use UUID in my Rust application. I didn't find any mention about in the documentation of Rust. Is there any standard, de-facto way to work with UUID in Rust?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the uuid crate: https://crates.io/crates/uuid.

Answer (score 18):

The uuid crate used to be a part of the Rust standard library, but it was [moved to a separate repository](https://crates.io/crates/uuid).

A code example generating a new UUID or parsing a existing UUID and getting many representations if:

```
use uuid::Uuid; // 0.8.1

fn show_uuid(uuid: &Uuid) {
    println!("bytes: {:?}", uuid.as_bytes());
    println!("simple: {}", uuid.to_simple());
    println!("hyphenated: {}", uuid.to_hyphenated());
    println!("urn: {}", uuid.to_urn());
}

fn main() {
    // Generate a new UUID
    let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();
    show_uuid(&uuid);

    // Parse an existing UUID
    let uuid = Uuid::parse_str("95022733-f013-301a-0ada-abc18f151006").unwrap();
    show_uuid(&uuid);
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add the v4 feature in Cargo.toml: uuid = { version = "0.8.1", features = ["v4"] }